# Problem with subfig, autoref and renewcommand

Tags: autoref

I have a problem with using the `autoref`

[image]

I want to change the format form 1a → Fig. 1(a)

What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}  
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor} \label{setting}  
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.}  
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}

\begin{document}  
    \begin{figure}[!t]  
        \centering  
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{A}\label{A}}  
        \\  
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{B}\label{B}}  
        \caption{LETTER }  
        \label{LETTER}  
    \end{figure}    

 The letter A is shown in \autoref{A}  
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please extend your example to a full example so we know what document class you are using. Also isn't `hyperref` suppose to be loaded **after** `subfig`?

Comment: I am so sorry I have not described my problem clearly. I have already re-edited it. Is this ok?

Comment: The label for the subref should probably so inside the subfloat, often `\subfloat[\label{...}]{...}` is used

Answer (score 1):

Since `A` is a label to a sub-figure (and not to a figure), try `\subfigureautorefname` instead of `\figureautorefname`:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}% \label{setting}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{Fig.}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!t]
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{A}\label{A}}
        \\
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{B}\label{B}}
        \caption{LETTER}
        \label{LETTER}
    \end{figure}

 The letter A is shown in \autoref{A}
\end{document}
```